# SQLAlchemy ORM - 3-some object relationships

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy with Postgres.
Code example from https://auth0.com/blog/sqlalchemy-orm-tutorial-for-python-developers/

I have 3 objects:

- Actor
- Stuntman
- ContactDetails

In the original code example, the relationships are as follow:

- Actor:ContactDetails = 1:0..*
- Actor:Stuntman = 1:1

See Code:

```
class Actor(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'actors'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    birthday = Column(Date)


class Stuntman(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stuntmen'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    active = Column(Boolean)
    actor_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('actors.id'))
    actor = relationship("Actor", backref=backref("stuntman", uselist=False))


class ContactDetails(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'contact_details'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    phone_number = Column(String)
    address = Column(String)
    actor_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('actors.id'))
    actor = relationship("Actor")
```

I'm struggling to extend this model to following relationships:

- Actor:ContactDetails = 1:0..*
- Actor:Stuntman = 1:1
- Stuntman:ContactDetails = 1:0..*

Stuntmen work hard too and deserve ContactDetails. Who can help please?!

Comment: One possibility is to remove `actor_id` from `ContactDetails` and add association tables joining `ContactDetails` to `Actor` and `Stuntman`.

Comment: Thanks @IljaEverilä. This is same as Cysio's solution, see below for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion best way to achieve what you need is using association table. This one should work:

```
actors_to_contact_details = Table('actors_to_contact_details', Base.metadata,
    Column('actor_id', Integer, ForeignKey('actors.id')),
    Column('contact_detail_id', Integer, ForeignKey('contact_details.id'))
)


stuntmen_to_contact_details = Table('stuntmen_to_contact_details', Base.metadata,
    Column('stuntman_id', Integer, ForeignKey('stuntmen.id')),
    Column('contact_detail_id', Integer, ForeignKey('contact_details.id'))
)


class Actor(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'actors'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    birthday = Column(Date)
    contact_details = relationship("ContactDetails", secondary=actors_to_contact_details)


class Stuntman(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stuntmen'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    active = Column(Boolean)
    actor_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('actors.id'))
    actor = relationship("Actor", backref=backref("stuntman", uselist=False))
    contact_details = relationship("ContactDetails", backref="stuntman", secondary=stuntmen_to_contact_details)


class ContactDetails(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'contact_details'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    phone_number = Column(String)
    address = Column(String)
```

if you want, you can put `unique=True` in association table like this

```
actors_to_contact_details = Table('actors_to_contact_details', Base.metadata,
    Column('actor_id', Integer, ForeignKey('actors.id')),
    Column('contact_detail_id', Integer, ForeignKey('contact_details.id'), unique=True)
)


stuntmen_to_contact_details = Table('stuntmen_to_contact_details', Base.metadata,
    Column('stuntman_id', Integer, ForeignKey('stuntmen.id')),
    Column('contact_detail_id', Integer, ForeignKey('contact_details.id'), unique=True)
)
```

Other option would be to put another nullable foreign key on `Stuntman` table, but I would go with solution presented above.

Comment: This makes perfect sense and works like a charm. Thanks you!